# MIPS MIDI Player: problems with playback and skip

Tags: mips

I have a couple of questions about my group project. The first question is regarding playback of a MIDI file. Right now our program can playback a type 0 file with about 75% accuracy (if you can even gauge that). Basically, it get "most" of the song right (or really close). It's clearly not playing every sound and some of the ones it does play sound distorted. So if it's playing most of the notes correctly, what could cause it to miss or distort the others?

The second question is concerned with our interrupt handler. I'm trying to adjust the pointer so the program will skip X bytes forward/backward, but if I try the interrupt while the program is running it stalls and locks the program up. If I run through the interrupt step-by-step it won't stall. It seems like I'm either halfway there or totally off the mark (this was working on an earlier version, but probably b/c the playback function wasn't written correctly). If I had to guess I'd say the problem has something to do with the WITH_STATUS and WITHOUT_STATUS functions. Is that right?

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
PLAY_MIDI:          
        addi    $s5, $0, 0          # temporaries to control speed and volume
        addi    $t6, $0, 100   
        addi    $t9, $0, 0          
        addi    $sp, $sp, -4            # add a byte to the stack pointer and store the return address there
        sw  $ra, 0($sp)
        addi    $t4, $0, 3
LOOP:
        lh  $t0, DAT_Format
        bnez    $t0, NO_SUPPORTED
        addi    $s3, $s3, 1
        addi    $s1, $s1, -1    
        lbu     $t9, 0($s3)             # look for status byte
        blez    $s1, OFF_LOOP
        bltu    $t9, 0x80, LOOP
        bgeu    $t9, 0xa0, LOOP
WITH_STATUS:
        lbu     $t9, 0($s3)
        lb  $t6, -1($s3)            #sleep time 
        lb  $a1, 1($s3)         # load note
        lb  $a2, 2($s3)             # load volume
        addi    $s3, $s3, 4
        addi    $s1, $s1, -4
        move    $s2, $s1        # *** copy $s1 to $s2  for pause/play
        j   SLEEP
WITHOUT_STATUS:
        lb  $t6, -1($s3)            #sleep time
        lb  $a1, 0($s3)         # load note
        lb  $a2, 1($s3)             # load volume
        addi    $s3, $s3, 3         #increase stack
        addi    $s1, $s1, -3
        move    $s2, $s1        # ** copy $s1 to $s2    for pause/play
SLEEP:

        mul     $t6, $t6, $t4
        li  $v0, 32             # sleep until the next note should be played
        addu    $a0, $0, $t6            # sleep for $t6 ms
        syscall

        and     $a0, $t9,0x0F           # load channel
        and     $t9,$t9,0x000000F0      # load Command

                                               ######################################################
                                               ## copy $s1 to $s2 for use differentiating between  ##
        beq     $t9, 0x90, PLAY_NOTE_ON     ## stop and pause                   ##
        beq     $t9, 0x80, PLAY_NOTE_OFF        ## $s2 will hold last position of $s1               ##
        bgeu    $t9, 0xa0, LOOP             ######################################################

AFTER_PLAY:         
        blez    $s1, OFF_LOOP
        lbu     $t0, 0($s3)
        bgeu    $t0, 0x80, WITH_STATUS
        j   WITHOUT_STATUS

OFF_LOOP:       
        bne $s1, $s2, PAUSE_LOOP        # get the return address from the stack and decrease the pointer
        lw  $ra, 0($sp)
        addi    $sp, $sp, 4
        jr  $ra             # jump to the address we just loaded
PLAY_NOTE_ON:
        li  $v0, 60             # add a byte to the stack pointer and store the return address there
        syscall 
        j   AFTER_PLAY          

PLAY_NOTE_OFF:
        li  $v0, 61
        syscall
        j   AFTER_PLAY

NO_SUPPORTED:
j EXIT

#### Below is part of the interrupt handler ####
SKIP_FORWARD:       addi    $s3, $s3, 1         # by adding to $s3 program will move pointer ahead 
        la  $a0, skip_forward       # changed from $s3 to $s1 ***
        li  $v0, 4
        syscall
        jr  $ra

SKIP_BACKWARD:      addi    $s3, $s3, -1            # by subtracting from $s3 program will move pointer backwards
        la  $a0, skip_backward      # changed $s3 to $s1
        li  $v0, 4
        syscall 
        jr  $ra
```